How to compare values of a key in a Python dictionary with multiple keys and values
I am trying to compute the euclidean distance between two coordinates (x,y), I have a Python dictionary that looks like this:
{1: [(17.186463384962565, -112.35762426972929),
  (-17.362219355529177, 140.79092146084173)],
 2: [(5.740268073287439, -83.6299751315692),
  (-51.314275844432835, 165.06524262125532)],
 3: [(1.7593699294955343, 136.62055358721852),
  (24.298602662279094, -156.1279333844176)],
 4: [(34.38895496244045, -110.77238417799168),
  (-76.86962027927443, -169.7646833442151)]}

Each key represent a customer and the values are coordinates, each customer has two different coordinates. I need to derive the euclidean distance between one customer location and another customer location, e.g., the euclidean distance between the first value for key 1 and the first value for key 2, next first value for key 1 and second value for key 2 and so on.
I have tried with this code:
distance = {}
for i in range(1, len(locations)+1):
    for j in range(1, len(locations)+1):
        if i != j:
            dist1 = euclidean_distance(locations[i][0], locations[j][0])
            distance[i,j] = dist1

But I'm just getting the distance between the first value for key 1 and the first value for the other keys, the distance between the first value for key 1 and the second value for the other keys is missing.  I want to get something like this:
{(1,2): distance; (1,3): distance; (1,20): distance; (1,2): distance; (1,3): distance; distance; (1,20)}


Your desired output is not very clear. You can't have the same key multiple times in a dictionary. If you want multiple values for the same key, you probably need to make the value a list (which can then contain the multiple real values).

Do you to keep track of all four distances for each pair of customers, or do you only need to keep the shortest or longest distance for each pair?   Is it guaranteed that each customer has exactly two sets of coordinates?

Where do the 20 values in your “I want” list come from?

I need to keep track of all the distances and yes each customer has two set of coordinates. The value 20 is the last key in my dictionary.

I'm not very sure what is the output you require but based on what I've understood this should work out for you.
distances = {}

for i in locations:
    for j in locations:
        if i != j:
            for index_i, loc_i in enumerate(locations[i]):
                for index_j, loc_j in enumerate(locations[j]):
                    key = (i, index_i + 1, j, index_j + 1)
                    dist = euclidean_distance(loc_i, loc_j)
                    distances[key] = dist

Let me know if this works out for you

Wonderful! Thank you so much, it worked. Any idea regarding how can the key be shorter? For instance when there are 5 or more pairs of locations the key will be too long. Thanks again.

As you've provided the pattern of the key it'll become longer as there will me more and more locations in that case you can change the key format and choose something unique and more simpler in that way the key wil be shorter and you avoid more complex combinations.
